# ReactJS 'guess the number game'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a very simple 'Guess The Number' game with ReactJS which seems to be working well except it executes when the user changes the input and not on the button click as I expected.

What am i doing wrong?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/guess-the-number-game-82z1n

Code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

const GuessTheNumber = () => {

const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const onChange = e => setValue(e.target.value);
let results = "";

const onClick = () => { 
    // check users guess against randonNumber
    const userGuess = value;
    if (userGuess == "") return null;
    if (userGuess == randomNumber ) return <p className="alert alert-success">Correct!</p>;
    if (userGuess > randomNumber) return <p className="alert alert-warning">Too high, guess again</p>;
    if (userGuess < randomNumber) return <p className="alert alert-warning">Too low, guess again</p>        
}

results = onClick(value)

return (
    <>
        <h2>Guess The Number game</h2>
        <p className="lead">Guess a number between 1 and 10.</p>
        <input value={value} type="number" onChange={onChange}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>GUESS</button>
        <br /><br />
        {results}

    </>
)
}

export default GuessTheNumber;
```

Comment: Everytime, the user changes the input, it calls `onChange` and therefore `setValue()` which then forces a rerender, because `value` changes. If it (re)renders, `result = onClick(value)` is called which executes the code you only want to be called by clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can set results as state and update it on `onClick` and use `else ... if` for check

```
const [results, setResult] = useState("");

const onClick = () => {
    // check users guess against randonNumber
    const userGuess = value;
    if (userGuess == randomNumber)
      setResult(<p className="alert alert-success">Correct!</p>);
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber)
      setResult(<p className="alert alert-warning">Too high, guess again</p>);
    else if (userGuess < randomNumber && userGuess !== "")
      setResult(<p className="alert alert-warning">Too low, guess again</p>);
    else setResult("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Guess The Number game</h2>
      <p className="lead">Guess a number between 1 and 10.</p>
      <input value={value} type="number" onChange={onChange} />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        GUESS
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {results}
    </>
  );
```

check here [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/guess-the-number-game-1pqmq)

Answer (score 0):

results = onClick(value) this statement class the onClick function every time you change the value of input. so i have updated the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

const GuessTheNumber = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [statement, setStatement] = useState("");

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    // check users guess against randonNumber
    const userGuess = value;
    if (userGuess === "") return null;
    if (userGuess === randomNumber) setStatement("<p className="alert alert-success">Correct!</p>");
    if (userGuess > randomNumber) setStatement("<p>Too high, guess again</p>");
    if (userGuess < randomNumber) setStatement("<p>Too Low, guess again</p>");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Guess The Number game</h2>
      <p className="lead">Guess a number between 1 and 10.</p>
      <input
        value={value}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClickHandler}>
        GUESS
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {statement}
    </>
  );
};

export default GuessTheNumber;
```

Comment: Hi Ferin, thanks for this. Worked a trick except I had to change the triple equals operator back to just a double as it doesn't work otherwise. Quick question, why did you move the input onChange function? Or is this just your own preference?

Comment: Its my own preference and to avoid confusion. Please accept my answer

Comment: @iamhuynq answer is not efficient.  and i have updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are always updating, because you are updating your state as soon as your input changes. This is still a good thing (as far as I know), but every time you update the state your whole component gets re-rendered, also the `results` object gets re-rendered and it gets recalculated because of this line:

```
results = onClick(value);
```

Therefore I'd suggest to also store the result in your state and only calculate it when the user clicks 'GUESS'.

NOTE: Please avoid comparisons with `==` in Javascript and always prefer `===` because its also checking type. Now it fails because you are comparing a number with a string -> check your datatypes and try to change it to `===`

NOTE 2: I'mm still a beginner with React too, so please excuse me if I didn't use good wording etc - thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Ferin and iamhuynq for helping me with this.

For anyone who comes across this question in the future, here is the working code including strict equality.

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/guess-the-number-game-82z1n

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// generate random number
let randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);

const GuessTheNumber = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState("");

  const onClick = () => {
    const userGuess = parseInt(value, setValue); // convert string to integer

    // If the user clicks 'Guess' without entering a number, ask them to pick a number
    setResults(<p className="alert alert-danger">Pick a number</p>);

    // If user input matches randomNumber, user guess is Correct!
    if (userGuess === randomNumber)
    setResults(<p className="alert alert-success">Correct!</p>);

    // If user input is higher than randomNumber, user guess is 'Too high'
    if (userGuess > randomNumber)
      setResults(<p className="alert alert-warning">Too high, guess again</p>);

    // If user input is lower than randomNumber, user guess is 'Too low'
    if (userGuess < randomNumber)
      setResults(<p className="alert alert-warning">Too low, guess again</p>);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Guess The Number game</h2>
      <p className="lead">Guess a number between 1 and 10.</p>
      <input
        value={value}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        GUESS
      </button>
      <br />
      <br />
      {results}
    </>
  );
};

export default GuessTheNumber;
```